# Manual white balance using Camera2 API on Google Pixel phones

Tags: android, android-camera2, google-pixel

I am accessing camera frames on Android using Camera2 API. All I want is to manually adjust the white balance of the images using `COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS`. This is my setup:

```
captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_MANUAL)

captureRequestBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_OFF)
val rggbChannelVector = RggbChannelVector(1.8f, 1.3f, 1.0f, 2.0f) 
captureRequestBuilder?.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS, rggbChannelVector)
```

On several Android devices I tested this works absolutely fine. Changing the values in the `rggbChannelVector` nicely adjusts the WB of the image. On Google Pixel phones it has zero effect, though.

The Camera2 documentation says the following about `COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS`:

> Full capability: Present on all camera devices that report being HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL devices in the android.info.supportedHardwareLevel key

I checked that key on the Pixel devices and it returned the required "FULL" Level.

Am I missing something in my setup, or is it really not possible to set a manual WB on the Pixel devices!? Thanks.

Comment: What about the `COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE`? The [COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS) documentation mentions that these are set by the camera device if the correction mode is not `TRANSFORM_MATRIX`. Maybe in Pixel, the correction mode is `FAST` or `HIGH_QUALITY`, so it is ignored. Also, maybe you can confirm if the values are reflected in the capture result frames as well.

Comment: That was the issue! Thanks! Setting the Mode to `TRANSFORM_MATRIX` and providing the necessary matrix via `COLOR_CORRECTION_TRANSFORM` did the job, now it works.